# Lower the volume when Google Map is giving direction and restore the volume once it finishes

Tags: java, android

---I am using Handler since mine is a radio application that always needs to play the music until it has been killed by the user. The result  I get is always 1---

```
    audioHandler=new Handler();
    audioHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mAudioManager.registerAudioPlaybackCallback(new AudioManager.AudioPlaybackCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPlaybackConfigChanged(List<AudioPlaybackConfiguration> configs) {
                        super.onPlaybackConfigChanged(configs);
                        mAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioFocusChangeListenerImpl();
                        int result = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusChangeListener,
                                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);


                        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                            Log.d("AudioFocus", "Audio focus received");

                            mFocusGranted = true;

                        } else if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED) {
                            Log.d("AudioFocus", "Audio focus NOT received");
                            mFocusGranted = false;

                        }




                        /* String message = "Focus request " + (mFocusGranted ? "granted" : "failed");*/
                        String message = "Focus request " + (mFocusGranted ? "true" : "false");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i(TAG, message);
                    }
                }, audioHandler);
            }
        }
    }, 500);

}
```

---- The change listener for Audio Focus which always runs but I can't figure out where i should lower and increase the volume.---

```
private class AudioFocusChangeListenerImpl implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        mFocusChanged = true;
        Log.i(TAG, "Focus changed");

        switch (focusChange) {
            /*case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                Log.i(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Focus GAINED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;*/
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                Log.i(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Focus LOST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                Log.i(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Focus  AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                break;
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                Log.i(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Focus LOST TRANSIENT CAN DUCK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can Lower or increase volume by hardware buttons :)

Comment: I do not want the user to manually increase/decrease volume, I need something like Spotify which decreases the volume during voice navigation in  Google Map.

Comment: during voice? can you describe this, can't understand

Comment: I am trying to do this with Audio Focus but what I am not able to  control  is the volume  increase or decrease of my media player whereas my application is granting permisasion to the voice navigation in Google Map then again sound from Navigation  it is hardly audible.